# Is a unicode code point can be displayed normally?

Tags: google-chrome, go

I want to know whether a unicode code point can be displayed in chrome, and check it in golang, so I can escape some parts of a string before i send it to chrome.

I have found that there is three types of unicode code point can not be displayed normally in chrome :

- Space . like code point 0x20(32). ' '
- Font not exist. There is a question mark in the square box. (occupy two English letters width) like code point 0x378(888) "͸"
- Invaild code point value. A diamond-shaped black box with a question mark inside (occupy one English letter width) like code point 0xd800(55296) "�"

Comment: @MuffinTop I want to check whether a unicode code point can be displayed in golang.

Comment: I want to know whether a unicode code point can be displayed in chrome, and check it in golang, so I can escape some parts of a string before i send it to chrome.

Answer (score -2):

I found that I can use js and OffscreenCanvas to render all of the unicode code point and check if them looks like above three types.

Then I got a function that can tell you whether a rune/character can be displayed normally by the operating system. https://github.com/fastslothlab/fslRune

js code:

```
(function(){
var start = 0;
var end = 1114111;
const imageSize = 20;
var tufoCiList = [32,888,55296];
var num = end-start+1;
var startTime = performance.now()
var hasDataCiList = [];
var c = new OffscreenCanvas(imageSize,imageSize);
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
function getImageDataByCi(ci){
    var s = String.fromCodePoint(ci);
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,imageSize,imageSize);
    ctx.fillText(s, 5, 15);
    var imgD = ctx.getImageData(0,0,imageSize,imageSize);
    var hasNoneZero = false;
    var buf = imgD.data;
    return buf;
}
var tofuBufList = [];
for (var i in tufoCiList){
    tofuBufList.push(getImageDataByCi(tufoCiList[i]));
}
function debugImage(){
     c.convertToBlob({
         type: "image/png",
     }).then(function(blob) {
         var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
         var imgObj = document.createElement("img");
         imgObj.src = url;
         document.body.appendChild(imgObj);
         console.log(url);
     });
}
function bufEqual(buf1, buf2){
    if (buf1.byteLength != buf2.byteLength) return false;
    for (var i = 0 ; i != buf1.byteLength ; i++){
        if (buf1[i] != buf2[i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
for (var ci =start;ci<=end;ci++){
    var buf = getImageDataByCi(ci);
    var hasFound = false;
    for (var i in tofuBufList){
        if (bufEqual(buf,tofuBufList[i])){
            hasFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (hasFound){
        continue;
    }
    hasDataCiList.push(ci);
}
console.log((performance.now()-startTime)/num);
console.log(JSON.stringify(hasDataCiList));
})();
```